# after i installed npm on my visual studio terminal to create react js app, when i node start the server its display error: module not found

Tags: reactjs

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\react-not-working\start'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use npm start

```
npx create-react-app (whatever you want)

npm start
```

Because it thinks you are going to run start.js